# 504 Gateway Time-out after custom plugin inserts data into mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have a custom plugin that inserts multiple rows into a custom table in the wordpress database. After about 50 seconds I get a `504 Gateway Time-out` error. The 50 seconds is around about the time it takes to insert ~400 rows. Anything less, and the script completes just fine.

I've added the usual things to `wp-config.php` and `.htaccess`

wp-config.php

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 1000);
ini_set('max_input_time', 1000);
set_time_limit(1000);
```

.htaccess

```
php_value memory_limit 256M
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 1000
php_value max_input_time 1000
```

...but none of these seem to make any difference. The script always timeout after about 50 seconds and I get `504 Gateway Time-out The server didn't respond in time` error screen.

My code:

```
global $wpdb;
$table = 'wp_motorjobs_jobs';
$insert_data = array();
```

Then I do a `foreach` loop where I prepare my data based on some other conditions. I end up with this array structure towards the end of the loop:

```
$job_data = array(
   'title' => $job_title,
   'company' => $job_company,
   'location' => $job_location,
   'type' => $job_type,
   'details' => $job_details,
   'query' => $search_query,
   'site' => $job_site,
   'url' => $url,
   'date' => $job_date
);                  
                
array_push($insert_data, $job_data);
```

Then I end my loop. This loop could have added hundreds of arrays to `$insert_data`. All the data are strings.

Then I prepare my sql query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO $table ( title, company, location, type, details, query, site, url, date ) VALUES ";
            
foreach ( $insert_data as $row ) {
   $query .= $wpdb->prepare( "(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s),", $row['title'], $row['company'], $row['location'], $row['type'], $row['details'], $row['query'], $row['site'], $row['url'], $row['date'] );
}

$query = rtrim( $query, ',' ) . ';';

$wpdb->query($query);
```

After this script runs for about 50 seconds I get the `504 Gateway Time-out`

Anyone? Cheers.

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: According to BrowserSPY it's BitNinja Captcha Server

Comment: BitNinja isn't a web server, it is rather some intrusion/DDoS prevention software. I will try to formulate the question differently - are you sure that it is apache web server that your hosting provider using, and not an nginx for example?

Comment: LiteSpeed Web Server

Comment: $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'] Apache

Comment: Maybe overriding this parameters is prohibited by hosting provider? You can check a `phpinfo()` output if your custom settings really applied. And maybe you'd better consult with the hosting tech support about it.

Comment: The custom settings did apply when I viewed phpinfo().

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Hey David :) So what's your question ;-) You seem to have done some good diagnosis work finding out the point the script causes things to go wrong, so what do you want to do about it? 50 seconds is a **lot** of time for 400 queries, things should go much faster than that. Maybe you want to share the specds of your server as it could be very underpowered, or ask your hosting company about this. Or look at ways to make this process more reliable?